# How can I get my folder path name and concatenate it with my file name?

Tags: vba, file-io

I'm using VBA Editor in Inventor to do this. I just used an OpenFileDialog that selects a *.iam file and displays the name in Form3.TextBox3.Text. From there, there is a shell set up to open the file. However, the shell doesn't know what it's opening with just the file name since the rest of the path is missing.

I've tried this several ways without luck, so I'm giving in and asking about it:
1) How can I get the folder path? From there I will set it as a string. (FileName is already a string.)
2) How can I concatenate the two strings to display together in the text box?

Much thanks!
Alyssa

RELEVANT CODE:

This is the Module that calls the OpenFileDialog:

```
Public Declare Function GetOpenFileName Lib "comdlg32.dll" Alias _
"GetOpenFileNameA"(pOpenfilename As OPENFILENAME) As Long
Public Type OPENFILENAME
lStructSize As Long
hwndOwner As Long
hInstance As Long
lpstrFilter As String
lpstrCustomFilter As String
nMaxCustFilter As Long
nFilterIndex As Long
lpstrFile As String
nMaxFile As Long
lpstrFileTitle As String
nMaxFileTitle As Long
lpstrInitialDir As String
lpstrTitle As String
flags As Long
nFileOffset As Integer
nFileExtension As Integer
lpstrDefExt As String
lCustData As Long
lpfnHook As Long
lpTemplateName As String
End Type
Public Function SelectFileOpenDialog()
Dim strTemp, strTemp1, pathStr As String
Dim i, n, j As Long
Dim OpenFile As OPENFILENAME
Dim lReturn As Long
Dim sFilter As String
Dim Fname As String
OpenFile.lStructSize = Len(OpenFile)
sFilter = "Assembly Files (*.iam)" & Chr(0) & "*.IAM" & Chr(0)
OpenFile.lpstrFilter = sFilter
OpenFile.nFilterIndex = 1
OpenFile.lpstrFile = String(257, 0)
OpenFile.nMaxFile = Len(OpenFile.lpstrFile) - 1
OpenFile.lpstrFileTitle = OpenFile.lpstrFile
OpenFile.nMaxFileTitle = OpenFile.nMaxFile
OpenFile.lpstrInitialDir = dir_path
OpenFile.lpstrTitle = "Select An Assembly"
OpenFile.flags = 0
lReturn = GetOpenFileName(OpenFile)
If lReturn = 0 Then
MsgBox "No file selected. Please try again."
Else
Fname = Trim$(OpenFile.lpstrFileTitle) ' copy the filename to "Fname"
n = FileLen(OpenFile.lpstrFile) 'length of the file
Resolve.FileName.Text = Fname

End If
End Function
```

This is the part of Form 3 that tries to open the assembly:

```
Private Sub Open_Button_Click()

Dim shell As Object
Set shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
shell.Open FileName

End Sub
```

Comment: @TimWilliams Added as requested

Comment: `OpenFile.lpstrFile` gives you the full path.  `OpenFile.lpstrFileTitle` is just the file name.

Comment: Yesss! You win :) It still doesn't open, but that's one step closer! Thanks so much!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I am hoping this will be helpful. It is a function I use in MS Access vba :

```
Public Function SelectFile(multi As Boolean, Optional filterName As String, Optional filterList As String, Optional defaultPath As String)
    Dim f As Object, vrtSelectedItem As Variant, s As String

    If Nz(filterName) = "" Then filterName = "All Files"
    If filterName = "All Files" Then filterList = "*.*"
    s = ""
    defaultPath = IIf(Nz(defaultPath, "") = "", CurrentProject.Path, defaultPath)
    Set f = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With f
        If (Dir(defaultPath, vbDirectory) <> "") Then .InitialFileName = defaultPath
        .AllowMultiSelect = multi
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add filterName, filterList, 1
        If .Show = -1 Then
            For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
                s = s & vrtSelectedItem & "|"
            Next vrtSelectedItem
            If s <> "" Then s = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)
        End If
    End With
    SelectFile = s
End Function
```

It's got parametrized all the input that the Application.FileDialog uses. It returns the complete path to the file selected, or in the case of multiple selection, each path concatenated with "|".

If you are not set about using the shell application, this will suit your needs. You can use the `InStrRev()` function to locate the last `\` in order to split the path into your file name and folder path.

Comment: Thank you! I will try that Monday morning and confirm if it worked or not!